# Django xhtml2pdf - Blank underline

Tags: html, django-templates, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to add a blank line in a table cell after some text, but due to xhtml2pdf's limitations, none of the `HTML` solutions are working. This is the closest I have gotten so far -

```
<td>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ value.label }}: </td>
            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

The main issue is that I want the blank underline to appear right after the text, but since the text length is variable, I cannot set a fixed width. Is there any way to set a `fit-to-width` property or an alternative approach to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact solution, but works for me. Given the font-size and pdf size is constant, an approximate cell width can be given using `|length` template tag and the other cell will have width `100 - length`. With some fine tuning, this is my code -

```
{% with label_length=value.label|length %}
{% with label_str=label_length|add:"1"|stringformat:"d" %}
    <tr>
        <td width="{{label_str}}%">{{ value.label }}:</td>
        {% with sub_val="-"|add:label_str %}
            <td width="{{100|add:sub_val}}%" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">&nbsp;</td>
        {% endwith %}
    </tr>
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```